# How to draw polygons in glut with input vertices from console window?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, polygon, freeglut

I am implementing 2D and 3D transformations in Glut project on codeblocks. But I am taking input vertices from the keyboard in console window. I want to pass these vertices to the glVertex2f(a,b) which lies inside display function.

```
void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(34,0,7.2);
    glColor3f(0,0,7.2);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(result1[0],result2[0]);
    glVertex2f(result1[0],result2[1]);
    // some more glvertex2f(,) 
    glEnd();
}
```

`display()` function is called in main as glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();
so that I can draw the polygon in glut window.
How can I do it ?

Comment: What are you asking? Seems like you already have it down, what more do you need?

Comment: I am not sure if you are using C or C++ please specify

Comment: i want to pass some vertices to the display function so that i can plot it on glut window using glVertex2f(a,b) function. I am using c++.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately GLUT works in a way where you cannot associate user-defined data to pass through callbacks, like this display callback.

As a result, you have to use some global variables which are accessible outside the scope of these callbacks in order to have access to the appropriate state.

So one way you can solve your problem is just input vertices in `main`, e.g., to global variables (file-scope statics, e.g.) you access in `display`. To avoid turning that into too big of a mess, you can use a single class or struct to kind of aggregate the data into a single global variable (or singleton or whatever).